# Python 3.11.5 Errno 2: No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python.
Been following a tutorial using VS Code but I’m stuck here, I have downloaded Python 3.11.5

```
PS C: \Users\ Pamire> code hello.py
PS C: \Users\ Pamire> python hello.py
C: \Users\Pamire \AppData\ Local \Programs \Python \Python311 \python.exe: can't open file 'C: \\Users\ \Pamire\ \hello.py': [Errno 2] No suc h file or directory
PS C: \Users \Pamire
```

And have been to Manage App execution Aliases and turned off the app installer and I have also added the path to the system variables but still I get the above error. Please help.

I thought after all the changes I made it was going to work automatically.
How can I fix this ?

Comment: Add more context, add full error code.

Comment: Have you actually saved `hello.py` in `C:\Users\<your username>`? Can you see the file in Windows Explorer`?

Comment: @FlyingTeller yes, I have.